# Accessing Amazon Pay Transaction Report via API

Tags: shopify, payment, aws-api-gateway, amazon-pay

I am currently trying to create a report of all amazon pay transactions. All data I need is included the "Amazon Pay Transaction Reports" which can be generated for a desired time period in the sellercentral interface. The report can then be downloaded as a CSV.

The amazon API documentation makes it seem like there is also the option to create and access this report programatically. (https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-checkout/set-up-reports.html)
Unfortunately the link in the documentation for further details seems to be broken.

Does anyone know how to access this endpoint or whether there is any other way to get the data for all transactions within given time period?

I was also looking at the other endpoints but unfortunately it seems like it is not possible to query multiple charges at the same time but only by a specific chargeId.

Answer (score 0):

the documentation link in that page should be corrected, but you can also access the Reporting API Integration Guide [here](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/amazonpayments/documentation/Settlement_Report_Documentation_US.pdf).